# Deploying multiple APK to market

Tags: android, resources, apk, packaging

I've got an Adroid application that works on devices with every density and screen sizes,
to achieve this I placed multiple resources in the "res" folder, as Android allows you to do.
Fact is that giving him resources for "low, mid, high and xhigh" resolutions makes my APK very large in terms of memory (~10 MB for a utility is way too much).
I already compressed al the images and so on.

So I suggest: 
is it a good practice to only provide one kind of resources and sign a package for every resolution i need?
e.g. package the app with just the low res folder, than erease it, substitute with higher res folder package again, and publish many apk (as skype does)?

If so, is there a way to automate this procedure? Like giving a tool or a script your project, resources and keystore? Or is there a better way to package an app that goes on EVERY device?

FYI: I'm using Appcelerator Titanium so the app is for API 8 or Higher, but the size problem does not relies in the usage of the framework, it "only" adds a couple of MB

Comment: just publish with muliple APK's Google suggests it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using android studio with gradle..Gradle provide better support for multiple builds.